# Selecting distinct value from one column and duplicates of another

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

I have the following query that returns the rows where there is duplicates on some field,

```
SELECT customer_id, first_nm, last_nm, middle_nm, member_id, secret_field 
FROM cust_tbl
WHERE secret_field <> '' AND
        secret_field IN (SELECT secret_field 
                                FROM cust_tbl
                                WHERE secret_field <> '' 
                                GROUP BY secret_field
                                HAVING COUNT(secret_field) >= 2

                        )`
```

Which returns the desired results, for example,

```
 customer_id | first_nm | last_nm | middle_nm | member_id | secret_field
      1      |  jane    |   doe   |           |    1005   | secretvalue1
      2      |  jane    |   doe   |           |    1005   | secretvalue1
      5      |  jane    |   doe   |     m     |    1060   | secretvalue1
      3      |  jon     |   doe   |           |    1010   | secretvalue2
      4      |  jon     |   doe   |     a     |    3030   | secretvalue2
```

The problem is I want only the rows where 'member_id' isn't duplicated, so the desired return value would be

```
 customer_id | first_nm | last_nm | middle_nm | member_id | secret_field
      1      |  jane    |   doe   |           |    1005   | secretvalue1
      5      |  jane    |   doe   |     m     |    1060   | secretvalue1
      3      |  jon     |   doe   |           |    1010   | secretvalue2
      4      |  jon     |   doe   |     a     |    3030   | secretvalue2
```

The duplicated member_id fields are removed. Additionally, there are rows where the the only thing that is different is the customer_id, I need these completely removed.

That is, if all of the rows with the same secret_field values have the same member_ids I would like those to not show at all but if the secret value is the same and there are rows with some of the same member_ids and some different memeber_ids I would want the distinct member_ids in this case.

I could work with a query that will give the distinct member ids where the secret value is the same, but there is more than one row.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And how do you choose which row you want?  Why 1 and not 2?

Comment: I need all of the rows where the secret_value is the same and where the member_id is not the same but where there is more than 1 row with the secret_value.

Answer (score 1):

Most versions of SQL support window functions.  You would write this as:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by secret_field, member_id order by member_id) as seqnum,
             count(distinct member_id) over (partition by secret_field) as cnt
      from cust_tbl c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1 and cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, tried this, it looks like this isn't supported with our database.

Comment: `distinct` in window functions?

Comment: @vkp . . . It is supported in most databases.  There are other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I have a bit of trouble understanding exactly what the intent is behind the query, but this should yield your desired 'result data'.  If this doesn't work on a more generalized case with your data, I will try to adapt it to your additional information.

For example, this assumes that everyone with the same member_id will have the same first_nm, last_nm, and middle_nm to meet your criteria.  If that is not the case, we could still do it, but we would have to select which name would be displayed on the row that you decided to show.

```
SELECT min(customer_id), count(distinct customer_id), first_nm, last_nm, middle_nm, member_id, secret_field 
FROM cust_tbl
WHERE secret_field <> '' AND
    secret_field IN (SELECT secret_field 
                            FROM cust_tbl
                            WHERE secret_field <> '' 
                            GROUP BY secret_field
                            HAVING COUNT(secret_field) >= 2

                    )
group by first_nm, last_nm, middle_nm, member_id, secret_field
having count(distinct customer_id) > 1
```